# How do I execute the mongodump command programmatically from node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

What is the best way to execute mongodb admin/console commands programmatically from node.js? Specifically, I would like to export a mongodb collection using mongodump after performing a series of inserts. Something like this:

```
// requires and initializing stuff left out for brevity
db.open(function(err, db) {
    if(!err) {
        db.collection('test', function(err, collection) {
            var docs = [{'hello':'doc1'}, {'hello':'doc2'}, {'hello':'doc3'}];

            collection.insert(docs, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {

                // Execute mongodump in this callback???

            });
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try using [`child_process.spawn(command, args)`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options):

```javascript
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

// ...
  collection.insert(docs, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {
    var args = ['--db', 'mydb', '--collection', 'test']
      , mongodump = spawn('/usr/local/bin/mongodump', args);
    mongodump.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
      console.log('stdout: ' + data);
    });
    mongodump.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
      console.log('stderr: ' + data);
    });
    mongodump.on('exit', function (code) {
      console.log('mongodump exited with code ' + code);
    });
  });
// ...
```

Comment: this was useful to me.I would like to add one more info."/usr/local/bin/mongodump" need to the the bin folder path of your mongodb,only then it works

Answer (score 1):

A different year, a different answer.

You can use something like [Shelljs](https://github.com/arturadib/shelljs)
to `exec` `mongodump` or any other commands that the UNIX shell provides.