# how to run mongodump command from child process?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, child-process, spawn, mongodump

I am trying to run the mongo dump command from child process here is the code from command prompt the command which is present inside cmd variable is working fine. using spawn it is not. I am not getting how to add mongo url and dump command inside child process.

```
var exec = require('child_process').spawn;
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

app.route('/export').get(async function(req, res) {
   var cmd = 'mongodump --db detailsDb--gzip --archive=d:\target.gz';
   var backupDB = exec([url, cmd]);
            backupDB.stdout.on('data',function(data){
                console.log('stdout: ' + data);// process output will be displayed here
            });
   })
```

Comment: What is the purpose of it being a child process ? Do you mean you need code working code to run the same command from node.js ?

Comment: @srinivasy yes ! i am unable to add local host and port in it

Comment: Did you check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210767/how-do-i-execute-the-mongodump-command-programmatically-from-node-js ?