# How to create installation script for app build on node.js, which include installation of dump of data base (mongo) , installation of camunda server?

Tags: node.js, automation, scripting, software-packaging

I am trying to build an installation script for an app which made on node.js. As of now, I have to manually install the database dump, run Mongo server, npm packages and run Camunda server. So, is there any way I can do all those things by running a single script.

Please bear with my silly question.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can call mongodump command from nodejs as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210767/how-do-i-execute-the-mongodump-command-programmatically-from-node-js)

about mongo server, you can start it in your app:

```
import { connect } from 'mongoose'; // MongoDB ORM
connect(conf.db[conf.env], {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  useCreateIndex: true,
})
  .then(() => console.log(`connected to ${conf.db[conf.env]}`))
```

I need to say above code is written in ES6, if you don't use it you need to set Babel or use older code style:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('url/of/your/db', {
{
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  useCreateIndex: true,
}, function (error) {
  if (error) { // do sth with error 
  }
  console.log('connected successfully');
}
```

I hope it helps you with your problem